# How to get javascript working in call QWebElement.appendInside('some html code')?

Tags: javascript, qt, dom, webkit

I am working on plugin for im client that will be show chatlog in QWebView. Plugin must support html templates. Now I’m trying to append new messages by call QWebElement.appendInside(‘new message’) and if in the template there is javascript source it does not work.
For example template may be such type:

```
<!--MessageIn-->
<div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="in MessageIn" id="oneShot">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="bl">
            <div class="br">
                <p class="head">
                    <span class="time" id="time">%time%</span>
                    <span class="name" id="name">%name%</span>
                </p>
                <p class="content">
                    <span class="text" id="text"><script>getitall('%text%','%name%','%cid%','%base%',meldungsart[0]);</script></span>
                </p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">animation1();</script>
```

Functions getitall() and animation1() won't be executed.

I can’t use QWebElement.evaluatejavascript() because i don’t know function names.

Comment: You can search for nodes in the template, then read its content and evaluate it.

Comment: There is another one problem with **evaluatejavascript()**: if **document.write()** is used in JavaScript function (in template) then the result of it will replace entire DOM.

Comment: it's my mistake. method **document.write** should not used in loaded page. **evaluateJavaScript** is suitable.

Comment: but some templates are still does not work normally because some JavaScript functions must be called before adding new elements to DOM.

Comment: so still there is no solution for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use JQuery. Look at this example

```
//QString add contains block of HTML code

QWebElement bodyElem = webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("body");
add = "var $bodyy=$('body');"
+ "$bodyy.append('" + add + "');"
+ "null;";
bodyElem.evaluateJavaScript(add);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and with this code it works:

```
//main.cpp:
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

//mainwindow.h:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebKit/QWebElement>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebFrame>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString str="<div class=\"space\">&nbsp;</div>"
                "   <div class=\"in MessageIn\" id=\"oneShot\">"
                "      <div class=\"tr\">"
                "         <div class=\"bl\">"
                "            <div class=\"br\">"
                "               <p class=\"head\">"
                "                  <span class=\"time\" id=\"time\">%time%</span>"
                "                  <span class=\"name\" id=\"name\">%name%</span>"
                "               </p>"
                "               <p class=\"content\">"
                "                  <span class=\"text\" id=\"text\">    <script>getitall('%text%','%name%','%cid%','%base%',meldungsart[0]);</script></span>"
                "               </p>"
                "            </div>"
                "         </div>"
                "      </div>"
                "   </div>";
    QWebPage *page = new QWebPage(this);
    ui->webView->setPage(page);
    QWebFrame *frame = page->mainFrame();
    frame->setHtml("<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">function displayDate(){     document.getElementById(\"time\").innerHTML=Date(); }</script></head><body><p>First     Paragraph</p><p>Second Paragraph</p><div id=\"void\">void</div></body></html>");
    QWebElement voiddiv = frame->findFirstElement("div#void");
    voiddiv.setInnerXml(str);
    voiddiv.evaluateJavaScript("displayDate();");
}


//mainwindow.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWebView" name="webView">
      <property name="url">
       <url>
        <string>about:blank</string>
       </url>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>18</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>QtWebKit/QWebView</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

//pro file:
QT       += core gui webkit

TARGET   = QWebViewTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES +=  main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

As you can see I created my own javascript function and I'm using that to test the code. The approach *should* be the same with any javascript methods. So you should customize your javascript and (x)html/xml code to get exactly what you need. But this should be a good start point ;)

Comment: As I said in first message, i could not use evaluatejavascript, for some reasons. Firstly, because I don't know names of JS functions and no, I don't want search them through whole template fragment.